# Boost.Python create handle from type

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

In some places in exposing C++ code to python, I need to use a `PyObject*`. If I have an instance of a `boost::python::class_` object, I can invoke `ptr()` on it. But what if I just have the type?

Basically, given the type list `boost::python::bases<A, B, C>`, I want to convert this to a `boost::python::tuple` of instances that I can pass into something like `PyErr_NewExceptionWithDoc()`. Is this possible?

Comment: In retrospect, even if this were possible, it's apparently impossible to create a python type that inherits from both a Python exception type and a Boost.Python `class_`. So I guess this is more curiosity than practicality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a C++ type `T`, one can create a [`boost::python::type_id`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/utility_and_infrastructure/boost_python_type_id_hpp.html#utility_and_infrastructure.boost_python_type_id_hpp.class_template_type_info) object, and then query into the Boost.Python registry for registration information.  If an entry is found in the registry, then one can use it to obtain a handle to the Python class created for type `T`:

```cpp
/// @brief Get the class object for a wrapped type that has been exposed
///        through Boost.Python.
template <typename T>
boost::python::object get_instance_class()
{
  // Query into the registry for type T.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::type_info type = python::type_id<T>();
  const python::converter::registration* registration =
    python::converter::registry::query(type);

  // If the class is not registered, return None.
  if (!registration) return python::object();

  python::handle<PyTypeObject> handle(python::borrowed(
    registration->get_class_object()));
  return python::object(handle);
}
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76fd7becde170616) locating a Python class object in the Boost.Python registry:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

/// @brief Get the class object for a wrapped type that has been exposed
///        through Boost.Python.
template <typename T>
boost::python::object get_instance_class()
{
  // Query into the registry for type T.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::type_info type = python::type_id<T>();
  const python::converter::registration* registration =
    python::converter::registry::query(type);

  // If the class is not registered, return None.
  if (!registration) return python::object();

  python::handle<PyTypeObject> handle(python::borrowed(
    registration->get_class_object()));
  return python::object(handle);
}

struct spam {};

int main()
{
  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    // Create the __main__ module.
    python::object main_module = python::import("__main__");
    python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    // Create `Spam` class.
    // >>> class Spam: pass
    auto spam_class_object = python::class_<spam>("Spam", python::no_init);
    // >>> print Spam
    main_module.attr("__builtins__").attr("print")(get_instance_class<spam>());
    // >>> assert(spam is spam)
    assert(spam_class_object.ptr() == get_instance_class<spam>().ptr());
  }
  catch (python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
<class 'Spam'>
```

For more type related functionality, such as accepting type objects, `is`, and `issubclass`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436270/1053968) answer.