# Boost-Python: Expose a class to Python which is a subclass of a Python class (str)

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am trying to have a Boost Python function return a Python object which is a subclass of a Python builtin class (here `str`):

My first method involves creating the class in a Python module, `mystr.py`:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self + other
```

I then import that module using Boost, and then to return a python object of that type I use somehting along these lines in C++, importing the module and calling `py::exec`:

```
py::object AsMyStr(std::string const &s)
{
    py::object my_str = py::import("mystr");
    py::dict my_namespace(my_str.attr("__dict__"));
    
    my_namespace["_MYSTR_test"] = s;
    py::exec(
        "_MYSTR_test = MyStr(_MYSTR_test)\n",
        my_namespace, my_namespace);
    return my_namespace["_MYSTR_test"];
}
```

Exposing this funtion in a Boost-Python module, this correctly gives me a `MyStr` instance on the Python side, which can be used accordingly:

```
 a = AsMyStr("Hello")
 b = " World"
 print(a / b)
 # "Hello World"
```

---

I just wonder if the subclassing of `str` can be done on the Boost-Python side of things in C++. I cannot manage to get `__truediv__` to work in that case:

```
class MyStr : public py::str
{
public:
    MyStr(py::object const &o) : py::str(o)

    MyStr __truediv__(other)
    {
         return MyStr(*this + other);
    }
 }
```

Exposing it as a module

```
 BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyStr)
 {
     py::class_<MyStr, py::bases<py::str>>("MyStr", py::no_init)
         .def(py::init<py::object const &>())
         .def("__truediv__", &MyStr::__truediv__)
         ;
 }
```

But using this class on the Python side leads to:

```
 a = MyStr("Hello")
 b = " World"
 print(a / b)
 # ValueError: character U+5555eaa0 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

How do I have to define and expose the class `MyStr` in the C++ implementation to return on the Python side a "true" MyStr which is a subclass of `str`?

---

I uploaded the code to https://gitlab.com/kohlrabi/learn-boost-python, the branch `master` contains the first solution, the branch `cpp_class` the second, non-working solution.

Answer (score 0):

The range U+0000 to U+10fffff represents [all possible Unicode code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).

Your string is likely to be encoded between C++ and Python, so you can try an encoding as in `.decode('cp1252')`. Or you can do `.decode('utf-8', 'surrogatepass')` and the bad characters will show as undecoded bytes in the resulting string.

Change `surrogatepass` to `replace` and they become question marks and change to ignore and they disappear.

Comment: The operation does not perform correctly. I don't think this solves the problem.

Comment: Please let me know more details. Has your output changed? Or do you get a different error message?

Comment: The overloaded operation `__truediv__` does not apply correctly.

Comment: Overloaded on C++ or python???

Comment: On C++. I think subclassing Python built-in classes from boost-python is simply not possible. I have found nothing of the sort anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried Cython instead?

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393063/pass-a-type-object-class-not-an-instance-from-python-to-c

Comment: Also this:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html

Comment: The first link looks interesting, thanks, @nferreira78.